# Can I use cubic-bezier() timing to make a 3D transform bounce

Tags: css, transform, bezier

I'm trying to create a submenu animation to have it drop in from behind it's parent menu like it's on a hinge. I want it to go a little past its final resting position, then come back. From my understanding of the `cubic-bezier()` functional notation, this should be possible. I'm not sure if it's a bug or just me misunderstanding but I can't seem to get it to work. I removed all of the vendor prefixes (they are in the demo) but here's the code I'm using:

### HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="about.html#company">Company</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="about.html#team">Team</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
ul {
    background-color:#99f;
    border-radius:10px;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul:after {
    clear:both;
    content:'';
    display:block;
    height:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}

.nav > li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    perspective:600px;
    perspective-origin:100% 100%;
    transition:background-color .2s .4s;
}

.nav li a {
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    padding:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.nav li ul {
    background-color:#bbf;
    border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
    position:absolute;
    transform:rotateX(-90deg);
    transform-origin:0 0 0;
    transition:transform .4s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.nav li:hover {
    background-color:#bbf;
    -webkit-transition-delay:0;
}

.nav li:hover ul {
    transform:rotateX(0);
    transition-delay:.2s;
}

.nav li li {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/ajasax/9/edit)

So based on the information from [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/timing-function#The_cubic-bezier%28%29_class_of_timing-functions), `cubic-bezier()` *can* have values greater than 1 on the Y axis, allowing for a bounce effect. In theory, this means the `cubic-bezier()` I'm using should make the submenu swing from -90deg, down to about 15deg, then back to 0deg.

Unfortunately, I'm not seeing that behavior. I do see that the `cubic-bezier()` affects the timing of the animation versus using no timing function at all, but it does not provide the bounce effect I expect.

I'm betting it has something to do with going from -90deg to 0deg and past but I'm super lost at this point. I've been unable so far to find any documentation on using `cubic-bezier()` curves with the `rotateX()` function to generate this type of effect or even documentation stating whether or not `rotateX()` supports this kind of rotation or what in the world is going on... help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third data in the transition property is a timing function (as you already say). In any way can change what happens in the transition (going to another coordinates, for instance)

I guess that your only option is using keyframes. (not so bad after all)

Of course you won't get a bezier interpolation, but I think that specifying 3 or 4 keyframes will make it good enough

**CORRECTION**

I was wrong.

Yes, bouncing effects can be done with a cubic-bezier.

You can get a cool page about that here

[easing transitions demo](http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/)

I guess that you problem is that not all properties  can be "bounced", or more exactly, that not all properties can be extended beyond the 100% limits of the transiton.

Sorry !

Comment: Could you clarify? I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me. I'm aware that I could accomplish the task with an animation, that's not an issue. What I'm trying to figure out is whether or not it's _possible_ to accomplish using `cubic-bezier()`, or more specifically some documentation about why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However according to the linked MDN article, that's not true. The third paragraph on the page states:

_The output ratio can be greater than 1.0 (or smaller than 0.0). This causes the animation to go farther than the final state, then come back, in a kind of bouncing effect._

This is why I anticipated the cubic-bezier function being able to do what I asked. Besically, the abscissas must be between 1 and 0, but the ordinate may be any value between, above, or below 1 and 0.

With that logic, the function I posted _should_ work.